# How Many Bytes Sent From SQL Server To Client

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

We are troubleshooting an ancient application written in classic ASP which accesses an SQL Server 2005 database.   This is an intranet application only.

The ASP page is set up to paginate through 200,000+ records, 10/20 or 30 records at a time.  We're planning to move this app to a more current language, etc.  In the mean time, we've been asked to determine how many bytes have been transfered to the client.

The SQL query is as such:

```
db_server = "<server name>"
db_name = "<database name>"
db_username = "<user name>"
db_userpassword = "<password>"

connectstr = "Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=" & db_server & ";DATABASE=" & db_name & ";UID=" & db_username & ";PWD=" & db_userpassword


With objCn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .ConnectionTimeout = 15
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .ConnectionString = connectstr
    .Open
End With

With objRs
    .ActiveConnection = objCn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .Source = sql
    .PageSize = intPageSize
    .Open
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset
End With
```

The ASP goes on to page through the return data and this is where we'd want to know how many bytes are actually received at the client.  We're thinking its simply taking the pagesize and multiplying it by the data field lengths being returned as the cursor only returns one "page" at a time.  Is it that simple?  Are we missing any significant overhead in that calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client and server are on different machines, fire up Wireshark to monitor the true bandwidth.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Yes, that is a great answer!  I will check that out.  The server is is located in another state actually.  Great!

Comment: No problem.  You'll want to use a capture filter to make sure you are only getting the right traffic (as opposed to Remote Desktop traffic, for example).  Probably the best way is to filter by port or by IP.

Comment: Oh yea.... I am seeing some other things that I need to look into as well.  This is excellent, thank you!